# Printing only one part of an object

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Using Python 3.8.0, this code

```
p = get_quote_yahoo("AUPH")
print(p)
```

gives result:

```
"language region quoteType  ...     market esgPopulated   price
AUPH    en-US     US    EQUITY  ...  us_market        False  19.825
[1 rows x 60 columns]"
```

and this code:

```
print(p.price)
```

gives:

```
"AUPH    19.8893
 Name: price, dtype: float64"
```

How do I access only the floating number (`19.8893`) in `p` so that only the number prints?

Comment: It's not clear what `p` or `p.price` is. What is `get_quote_yahoo`?

Comment: That depends on the type of `p`, i.e. what type of object does `get_quote_yahoo()` return?

Comment: Is this a dataframe? Can you include how you created this data structure?

Comment: Here's the entire program: 
from pandas_datareader import get_quote_yahoo                                       
p = get_quote_yahoo("AUPH")
print(p.price)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(p.price.values[0])
```

Comment: I like this answer the best, doesn't call other functions just places the pointer at the correct position in the object.  Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Since `p.price` is a [Series object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html) you can use all the methods available.

This is the correct way to get the value

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

p = pdr.get_quote_yahoo('AUPH')

print(next(iter(p.price)))
```

Or

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

p = pdr.get_quote_yahoo('AUPH')

print(p.price.get(0))
```

Or

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

p = pdr.get_quote_yahoo('AUPH')

print(p.price[0])
```

Outputs

```
# > python test.py
20.01
```

Comment: The last one with the index is the cleanest, and the one I suspected had to exist.  New to Python, I'm an old C, C+ programmer.

Comment: yes, the index is the best I believe. That's a `Series` is a container for lists of values so it supports multiple API to access the underlying data of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have this string:

```
m = """AUPH    19.8893
    Name: price, dtype: float64"""
```

If you use `split` method you will have:

```
>>> m.split()
['AUPH', '19.8893', 'Name:', 'price,', 'dtype:', 'float64']
>>> m.split()[1]
'19.8893'
>>> float(m.split()[1])
19.8893
```

So, for your case, You can get the number by doing:

```
m = p.price
result = float(m.split()[1])
print(result) # will display 19.8893
```

Comment: But look how clean Anatoli's answer above is.